# Create db connection from ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro to a regular non-spatial PostgreSQL database

Tags: arcmap, postgresql, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, database

When I attempt to create a database connection via ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro to a pure tabular PostgreSQL database, I keep getting insufficient permissions error.

I know it is not a permissions issue.

Is there a trick to being able to just connect to a non-spatial PostgreSQL database?

Comment: The thing about permission errors is that they're never wrong (database clients don't generally make up their own errors). I've never intentionally tried to connect to a PG database without a PostGIS extension, but I believe I have, so that might not be the issue either. If you enable a low-level trace, you can review the trace log for the exact error.

Comment: I can connect via pgAdmin and dbeaver access all the tables and everything once arcgis comes into the picture I get insufficient permission.